# ValueError in simple Python calculation

Tags: python, numpy

This is my function and the variable tracks is a list and each element of the list is a `n x 3` array:

```
temp = np.array(np.zeros((n, n)))
for j in range(n-1):
    for w in range(j + 1, n):  
        mindistance = np.zeros(len(tracks[j]))
        for i in range(len(tracks[j])):   
            mindistance[i] = np.linalg.norm(min(np.fabs(np.array(tracks[w]) - tracks[j][i])))
        temp[j][w]=np.sum(mindistance)/len(tracks[j])
```

I'm trying to calculate the minimum distances between the arrays of the list which represent 3d lines in space but I am getting the error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().

The error is probably related to the call to `min()` but I can't solve it. Following is the error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-14-7fb640816626>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/G_Laza/Desktop/functions/Main.py', wdir='/Users/G_Laza/Desktop/functions')

  File "/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 580, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/Users/G_Laza/Desktop/functions/Main.py", line 42, in <module>
    tempA = distance_calc.dist_calc(len(subset_A), subset_A)  # distance matrix calculation

  File "distance_calc.py", line 23, in dist_calc
    mindistance[i] = np.linalg.norm(min(np.fabs(np.array(tracks[w]) - tracks[j][i])))

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Please post the complete Traceback.

Comment: How far into the nested loops does it get before it throws the error?  What is the value of ```np.fabs(np.array(tracks[w]) - tracks[j][i])``` when it throws the error?

Comment: the value is an array and it stops in the first calculation.

Comment: Just to check whether the error is in `min`, did you try using `np.min()` or `np.amin()`?

Comment: An array of ints, floats, bools?  Do you understand what the error means - try ```if np.ones(4) == 1: pass``` in the shell. Have you tried adding statements with just portions of that line to see which part of the calc is causing the problem, then looking at the values of those operands to see why it is happening?

Comment: It's an array of floats but no, i don't understand the error and i don't have the skills to debug it b/c i'm new to Python.

Comment: @MatheusPortela you should post that as an answer with, simple 1-d and 2-d array examples.

Comment: @MatheusPortela i used the built-in min()

Comment: @GeorgeLaza: the first step in debugging this would be to write the three functions that you are calling in the line that throws the error as separate lines.  That is, `temp0 = np.array(tracks[w]) - tracks[j][i])`; `temp1 = np.fabs(temp0)`; etc.  This way, you can both see when function is actually throwing the error, and what its inputs are, eg, what's the shape of `temp1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because you cannot determine whether a complete array is `True` or `False`. What would be the boolean state of an array where all elements are `True` but one?

`min` takes an iterable for an argument and compares each element to the other, each comparison *results* in a boolean value.  Iterating over a 1-d `numpy` array produces individual elements - `min` works for a 1-d numpy array.

```
>>> a
array([-4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4])
>>> for thing in a:
     print thing,


-4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4
>>> min(a)
-4
>>>
```

Iterating over a 2-d `numpy` array produces rows.

```
>>> b
array([[-4, -3, -2],
       [-1,  0,  1],
       [ 2,  3,  4]])
>>> for thing in b:
     print thing

[-4 -3 -2]
[-1  0  1]
[2 3 4]
>>>
```

`min` won't won't work for 2-d arrays because it is comparing arrays and - `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous`.

```
>>> c
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
>>> c < 2
array([ True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> bool(c < 2)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#74>", line 1, in <module>
    bool(c < 2)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
>>> 
>>> bool(np.array((True, True)))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#75>", line 1, in <module>
    bool(np.array((True, True)))
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
>>> 
>>> bool(np.array((True, False)))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#76>", line 1, in <module>
    bool(np.array((True, False)))
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
>>>
```

If you need to find the *element* with the minimum value, use `numpy.amin` or the `ndarray.min` method.

```
>>> 
>>> np.amin(b)
-4
>>> b.min()
-4
>>>
```